# Javascript object not read

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

```
{"ma-steps":"{\"temp_token\":\"5dsed8dfsfsfdfdfsff0145059bd008a1e1a00247b92880bf9de56b153b289c9463c3dbda9f20f47fb9aca94e82ffba5dc2cd566f4c859\",\"reload_ma\":true}","google.message_id":"0:15917211468dfdsfsdfsd","google.sent_time":345543534}"
```

That is printed when I call JSON.stringify(payload))
However when I do var target = payload.ma-steps.temp_token;, It doesn't seem to work I get error 
ReferenceError: steps is not defined

Comment: payload['ma-steps'].temp_token;

Comment: i am getting undefined on temp_token part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dash, `-`, indicates subtraction and so can't be used in variable names. `payload.ma-steps.temp_token` is treated like `payload.ma` minus `steps.temp_token`. It is expecting a variable named `steps`, which doesn't exist, hence the error, "steps is not defined".

Instead, you can use object notation to access that property.

```
let target = payload['ma-steps'];
```

It appears that the value of `ma-steps` is a JSON formatted string, so you'll need to parse that before referencing any properties inside it.

```
let steps = JSON.parse(payload['ma-steps']);
let target = steps.temp_token;
```

Here is a working example:

```js
var payload = {"ma-steps":"{\"temp_token\":\"5dsed8dfsfsfdfdfsff0145059bd008a1e1a00247b92880bf9de56b153b289c9463c3dbda9f20f47fb9aca94e82ffba5dc2cd566f4c859\",\"reload_ma\":true}","google.message_id":"0:15917211468dfdsfsdfsd","google.sent_time":345543534};

let steps = JSON.parse(payload['ma-steps']);
let target = steps.temp_token;

console.log(target);
```

Comment: I get undefined for both cases. payload['ma-steps'] returns {"temp_token":"dfdsfdsfdsfsdfsd","reload_fences":true}"

Comment: yes exactly. it works that way , let steps = JSON.parse(payload['ma-steps']);

Answer (score 0):

I use your object and it works like I said on previous comment. Maybe the object is not well formed!

```js
let object = {
  "ma-steps": {
    temp_token:
      "5dsed8dfsfsfdfdfsff0145059bd008a1e1a00247b92880bf9de56b153b289c9463c3dbda9f20f47fb9aca94e82ffba5dc2cd566f4c859",
    reload_ma: true
  },
  "google.message_id": "0:15917211468dfdsfsdfsd",
  "google.sent_time": 345543534
};

console.log(object['ma-steps'].temp_token);
```

Comment: the part of ma-steps you provided works, but reload_ma gives undefined. strangely it works on web, but not on android mobile using cordova

Comment: So the problem is with Cordova not with the Javascript Object

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `payload.ma-steps.temp_token === (payload.ma) - (steps.temp_token)`, and will throw an Exception, unless `payload.ma` and `steps.temp_token` are both defined and numeric. So you want to access `payload['ma-steps'].temp_token`.

---

Assuming that your object was, originally:

```js
const obj = {
    'ma-steps': {
        temp_token: "5dsed8dfsfsfdfdfsff0145059bd008a1e1a00247b92880bf9de56b153b289c9463c3dbda9f20f47fb9aca94e82ffba5dc2cd566f4c859",
        reload_ma: true
    },
    google.message_id: "0:15917211468dfdsfsdfsd",
    google.sent_time: 345543534
};
```

The returned string is of `JSON.stringify(obj)`:

```
'{"ma-steps":{"temp_token":"5dsed8dfsfsfdfdfsff0145059bd008a1e1a00247b92880bf9de56b153b289c9463c3dbda9f20f47fb9aca94e82ffba5dc2cd566f4c859","reload_ma":true},"google.message_id":"0:15917211468dfdsfsdfsd","google.sent_time":345543534}'
```

However, if your object is actually:

```js
const obj2 = {
    'ma-steps': "{\"temp_token\":\"5dsed8dfsfsfdfdfsff0145059bd008a1e1a00247b92880bf9de56b153b289c9463c3dbda9f20f47fb9aca94e82ffba5dc2cd566f4c859\",\"reload_ma\": true}",
    google.message_id: "0:15917211468dfdsfsdfsd",
    google.sent_time: 345543534
};
```

`JSON.stringify(obj2)` returns what you've said:

```
'{"ma-steps":"{\"temp_token\":\"5dsed8dfsfsfdfdfsff0145059bd008a1e1a00247b92880bf9de56b153b289c9463c3dbda9f20f47fb9aca94e82ffba5dc2cd566f4c859\",\"reload_ma\": true}","google.message_id":"0:15917211468dfdsfsdfsd","google.sent_time":345543534}'
```

But, in this case, `obj2['ma-steps']` is a string, and doesn't have `temp_token` property. So you have to do:

```js
const ma_steps_parsed = JSON.parse(obj2['ma-steps']);
const target = ma_steps_parsed.temp_token;
```